# Navbar Bootstrap allowing one item to be outside hamburger glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have implemented a piece of code. When the browser window decrease in size (width-ways) the menu tabs enter into a clickable Hamburger glyphicon.

I would like to maintain this feature, but add one navigation tab outside the glyphicon when the browser reduces in size.

How is this possible using bootstrap? I attempted to add another

```
<div class="navbar"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> <li> </li> </ul> </div>
```

prior to the one ID'd "mainNavBar" however this led to poor formatting, which I thought might be able to be fixed by floating the two divs next to each other, but I couldn't work out the code to do that.

Below is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Logo -->

      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>

        </button>

        <a href="../homepage.html" class="navbar-brand"> Markets</a>

      </div>

      <!-- menu items -->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li> <a href="../aboutus.html">About Us</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../news.html">News</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../analysis.html">Analysis</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../randomarticle.html">Random Article</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../contactus.html">Contact Us</a>

          </li>

      </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navigation Bar -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/Vky1AGlU5F

**CSS**:

```
.still_on_view{
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Logo -->

      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>

        </button>

        <ul class="still_on_view nav navbar-nav">

          <li> <a href="../aboutus.html">About Usb2</a> 
          </ul>
        <a href="../homepage.html" class="navbar-brand"> Markets</a>

      </div>
      <div>

      </div>

      <!-- menu items -->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li> <a href="../aboutus.html">About Us</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../news.html">News</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../analysis.html">Analysis</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../randomarticle.html">Random Article</a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="../contactus.html">Contact Us</a>

          </li>

      </div>
  </nav>
```